# Dynamic Object Using Php $obj = new stdClass();

Tags: php, object

How can I create n numbers of dynamic object using loop like :

```
$obj->data1 = $response1; 
$obj->data2 = $response2;
$obj->data3 = $response3;
$obj->data4 = $response4;
```

and so on...  I don't want to create array i want only object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$obj = new stdClass();
for($i=1;$i<=4;$i++)
   $obj->{"data".$i}=${"response".$i};
```

**[Fiddle](https://eval.in/467799)**

You can change that loop to go as high as your actual number of variables.

Comment: Thanks a lot,  this is exactly what i was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

in your example you are creating properties of dynamic object, not objects them selves. If you want multiple objects you have to store them somewhere like variables:

```
$var1 = new stdClass();
$var2 = new stdClass();
```

Or in array:

```
$var[] = new stdClass();
```

Or in traversable:

```
$collection->addElement(new stdClass());
```

Comment: Thank for your help, but this approach can not help me in my situation as i already mentioned i want n numbers, in your suggested solution i must be aware of no of objects and well i am not because my no of objects depends on count in loop.

Comment: hi, if you use an array or a traversable to store your objects you do not need to know how many of them you have

Comment: yeah right but I needed simple solution with control, thanks for your support !